# Code crashes at iteration 86

Tags: axapta, x++

```
static void Job47(Args _args)
 {
 str                                  path,stx;
 TreeNodeIterator                     iter;
 TreeNode                             treeNode, treeNodeToRelease;
 Map                                  dictMenuDisplay;
 FormName                             formName;
 MenuItemName                         menuItemName;
 container                            conMenu;
 int                                  i,n;
   ;

 for (n=1;n<=100;n++)
       {
        info(strfmt("iter:%1",n));
        path            ="Menu Items\\Display";
        dictMenuDisplay = new Map(Types::String,Types::Container);
        treenode        = Treenode::findNode(path);
        iter            = treenode.AOTiterator();
        treenode        = iter.next();

        while (treenode)
          {
          formName     = treenode.AOTgetProperty("Object");
          menuItemName = treenode.AOTname();

           if (dictMenuDisplay.exists(formName))
            {
             conMenu = dictMenuDisplay.lookup(formName);
             conMenu = conIns(conMenu,conlen(conMenu)+1,menuItemName);
             dictMenuDisplay.insert(formName,conMenu);
             }

           else
             dictMenuDisplay.insert(formName,[menuItemName]);
                      //  treenode = iter.next();

           if(treeNodeToRelease && SysTreeNode::isApplObject(treeNode))
            {
             treeNodeToRelease.treeNodeRelease();
             treeNodeToRelease=null;
            }

           if(SysTreeNode::isApplObject(treeNode))
            {
              treeNodeToRelease=treeNode;
            }

            treeNode=iter.next();
        }
    }
  }
```

I get the error "overflow in internal run stack",the code runs till 86th iteration correctly, help...

Comment: I think it would be easier to get help if you improve the formatting of the posted code (less empty lines, shorter lines, better indentation, ...)

Answer (score 3):

The kernel doesn't immediately garbage collect TreeNode objects. Once you are done with a treenode for an application object and all it's children, you need to call `TreeNode.treeNodeRelease()`, followed by `treeNode=null;` to let the garbage collector clean up.

```
...
TreeNode treeNodeToRelease;
...

while(treenode)
{

    ... /* do stuff with treenode */

    if(treeNodeToRelease && SysTreeNode::isApplObject(treeNode))
    {
        treeNodeToRelease.treeNodeRelease();
        treeNodeToRelease=null;
    }
    if(SysTreeNode::isApplObject(treeNode))
    {
        treeNodeToRelease=treeNode;
    }
    treeNode=iter.next();
}
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Hofacker after following your suggestions i made modifications in my code, you could see that in the above code. Unfortunately the problem still persists. Kindly Help.

Comment: What I am trying to do is extract all existing Form name with them display menuitems.

Comment: Why are you iterating 100 times? If you just need a list of forms, you only need to traverse the AOT once.

Comment: yes i can do that but i want to test the use of garbage collector, code like TreeNode.treeNodeRelease(), treeNode=null I want to use them just for knowledge sake. And also curious to know wy the present code is not working, I hope u'd understand.(im new to AX so eager to learn more)

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
 if(treeNodeToRelease && SysTreeNode::isApplObject(treeNode))
```

should be replaced by:

```
 if (treeNodeToRelease)
```

The release of the object should not depend on the next object.

or maybe this is enough (supplanting Jay's solution):

```
while (treenode)
{
    ... /* do stuff with treenode */
    treeNode.treeNodeRelease();
    treeNode = iter.next();
}
```

Comment: thanks Jan for the suggestion, but what i see here is putting  treeNode.treeNodeRelease(); wont let traverse the whole(3064)nodes. It stucks in first node only.

Comment: It depends on the next object because you shouldn't release a tree node that represents an application object while you are still processing child nodes of that object. Once you are processing the next application object, you can release the previous one.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I applied the changes as you suggested and also edited my code(u can see the changes above). I still get the error "overflow in internal run stack" i think GC has nothing to do with this(im nt sure, kindly correct me if I am wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the manual:

> If you run this method (*treeNodeRelease()*) on many tree nodes in the same execution, it can be demanding on resources. You should unload the tree nodes as you go along to give the garbage collector a chance to remove them.
>
> Make sure to remove all references to the tree node and its subnodes before you call this method.

Also you have at least 85 references of the treeNodeToRelease (and treeNode!) floating around -> call *treeNodeToRelease.treeNodeRelease()* at the end of your outer loop.